# How do correlation between multiple dataframes ? Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, correlation

I have multiple df like this:

```
df1:

date_time               Value(0 or 1)
2020-08-28 07:33:52     0
2020-08-28 08:08:51     0
2020-08-28 08:31:31     0
2020-08-28 08:31:59     0
2020-08-28 08:34:44     0
2020-12-24 10:10:08     1


df2:

date_time             rpm
2020-08-27 20:42:02   0.000000
2020-08-28 07:31:12   0.000000
2020-08-28 07:33:04   0.000000
2020-08-28 08:28:53   -0.001589
2020-08-28 08:29:51   -0.001589
2020-08-28 18:21:42   104.971931


df3:

date_time               Step
2020-08-28 07:33:52     1
2020-08-28 08:08:51     5
2020-08-28 08:31:59     10
2020-08-28 08:34:44     15
2020-08-28 08:36:26     20
2020-12-07 16:49:22     25
```

I would like to study the correlation between this dataframes, but I have a technical question, do I have to merge the dataframes and do correlation between columns ? or there is an other way ?  and how do to it ?

As you can see the seconds columns for each df are completely differents (others units).

Comment: Your time stamps don't line up in the yorur datafarmes, how would you handle that?

Comment: I think I need do use `Serie.align`. (Here it is a piece of df)

Answer (score 0):

### If you want to merge to the nearest timestamp

```
df1['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date_time'])
df2['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date_time'])
df3['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df3['date_time'])

out = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on='date_time')
out = pd.merge_asof(out, df3, on='date_time')
out.corr()
```

### If you want to ignore the timestamps and instead simply concatenate

```
pd.concat([df1,df2['rpm'],df3['Step']], axis=1).corr()
```

These will yield different results, because merge_asof is looking at the timestamps and merging the values together on the closest timestamp from df1